# How to determine values of parameters such that an inequality is satisfied?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Given inequality `f[x, y]>0` where `f[x, y]=1/16 (-1 + x (2 - x + x^3 (-1 + y)^2 y^2))`, how can one find the values `x` (keeping `y` fixed) such that the inequality is satisfied. And then repeat the same to find `y` (keeping `x` fixed)? The answer appears in equation (107) [of this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07747.pdf):

$$2(\sqrt{2}-1) \le x \le 1, \qquad \frac{1}{2}\left( 1- \sqrt{ \frac{x^2 +4x - 4}{x^2} } \right) \le y \le \frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\sqrt{ \frac{x^2 +4x - 4}{x^2} } \right)$$

Edit: The parameters $x$ and $y$ satisfy $0\le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.

A similar but related problem with four variables $0\le x1 \le 1$, $0\le y1 \le 1$, $0\le x2 \le 1$, $0\le y2 \le 1$, and this time

```
 f[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_]=1/128 (2 + x1 (-2 + x2) y1 + (-2 + x1) x2 y2) (1 + x1 (-1 + y1) + 
   x2 (-1 + y2) - 
   1/2 x1 x2 (-2 + y1 + y2)) (-4 (-1 + x1) (-1 + 
      x2) - (x1 (-2 + x2) y1 + (-2 + x1) x2 y2) (-2 x2 (-1 + y2) + 
      x1 (2 - 2 y1 + x2 (-2 + y1 + y2))))
```

Comment: I recommend editing the question with a brief explanation what `x` and `y` stand for and what the inequality means.  Moreover the title should be restricted to Information-theoretic or/and quantum compiting ideas. Then the question would be more interesting for readers searching for related topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is not precisely formulated. Nonetheless we can reconstruct reasoning behind the result obtained in the article metioned.

Let's define

```
f[x_, y_] := 1/16 (-1 + x (2 - x + x^3 (-1 + y)^2 y^2))
```

then it is straightforward to exploit `Reduce` this way:

```
Reduce[ f[x, y] > 0, y]
```

nevertheless the result is much more involved than the formula (107).  So we deduce that the both `0 <= x <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 1` should be satisfied as well, and so we get

```
Reduce[f[x, y] > 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, y]
```

> ```
>   2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) < x <= 1 && 
>  1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] < y < 1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2]
> ```

analogically we can obtain the result assuming that `y` is fixed by

```
Reduce[f[x, y] > 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, x]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have a similar problem, but this time with 4 parameters (as given in the edited section). Do you see any hope of finding similar "ranges" for  x1, y1, x2, y2?